# Why golang map solution O(1) is slower than loop solution O(n) solution?

Tags: go, memory

I was solving leetcode [maximum69Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-69-number/description/) and I came up with 2 solutions.

1. Create a map with all the possible answers and just return the value in the map by input. (6ms)
2. Loop from the digit from the left. If you see a 6, add 3 * 10^x. (2ms)

My understanding is golang map is using hashmap and should be O(1) average. How could we explain that the O(1) solution is slower than the loop solution?

Another question is: how could I examine a program while it's running? Am I able to trace stack and heap history some how?

```
func maximum69Number (num int) int {
    return map[int]int{
        6666: 9666,
        9666: 9966,
        6966: 9966,
        9966: 9996,
        6696: 9696,
        9696: 9996,
        6996: 9996,
        9996: 9999,
        6669: 9669,
        9669: 9969,
        6969: 9969,
        9969: 9999,
        6699: 9699,
        9699: 9999,
        6999: 9999,
        9999: 9999,
        666: 966,
        669: 969,
        696: 996,
        699: 999,
        966: 996,
        969: 999,
        996: 999,
        999: 999,

        66: 96,
        69: 99,
        96: 99,
        99: 99,

        6: 9,
        9: 9,
    }[num]
}
```

```
func maximum69Number (num int) int {
    m := 1000
    for m > 0 {
        n := num / m % 10
        if n == 6 {
            return num + 3 * m
        }

        m /= 10
    }
    return num
}
```

Comment: Complexity doesn't tell you anything about exact running time, only about how it varies with the input. You function is creating a new map every time you invoke it. This involves memory allocations which is relatively expensive. Create the map outside the function. Or, turn it into a big `switch` statement, that will probably be even faster.

Comment: A O(1) algorithm beats a O(n) algorithm for n > some limit K. K might be absurdly high like 45900000000.

Comment: In other words, complexity analysis discards constant coefficients, but with small n values, you need to take that constant into account.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of a program doesn't affect the running time that much with small inputs like this. The complexity of a program measures how fast the running time grows with bigger inputs instead of providing an exact measurement of the running time which depends also on the constant of different operations.